# Weka setClassIndex and databases

Tags: java, database, weka

i'm using some sort of hello world example for the Weka API. I discovered a problem while creating Instances from a database.
**The situation:**
i have a database with two tables trainset(id, value, classValue) and testset(id, value, classValue).

Each table contains 10 rows of some example data, which should be classified 100% correctly. The first row in trainset is (1, 5, "low") and the first row in testset is (1, 15, "high").

When Weka creates the **Instances** object it seems to automatically create a class Attribute object as well.

```
train = query.retrieveInstances();
train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() - 1);
```

The class attribute for the first set is

```
@attribute classValue {low,high}
```

... and for the second

```
@attribute classValue {high,low}
```

When i run an evaluation it shows

```
Incorrectly Classified Instances        10              100      %
```

which is caused by the mixed up classValue attribute.

Is there any way i can tell up front how the class attribute should look like or can i change the mapping somehow?
I allready tried

```
FastVector fvClassVal = new FastVector(2);
fvClassVal.addElement("low");
fvClassVal.addElement("high");
Attribute classAttribute = new Attribute("classValue", fvClassVal);
test.setClass(classAttribute);
```

but that doesn't seem to work, it still wants to know the classIndex and overwrites the former attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I have asked and answered same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792905/same-instances-header-arff-for-all-my-database-queries)  before. You need to create a correct Arff header and use it before querying your database.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your hint. It really seems that there is no elegant solution right now. If you can assume that your test data will contain every class the training data has, you can modify the query:

SELECT value, classValue FROM trainset ORDER BY classValue

It is a solution with less code modification, but with a performance downside :/